# Attempt to present <xViewcontroller> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the option to play some media, if I link it to an IBAction on ViewController.h it will play fine.
The problem occurs, when I try to call that, from another ViewController, for example;

```
 ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [myViewController showVideos];
```

This is called from SecondViewController and refers to the code in ViewController.m

```
-(void)showVideos {

    [[ApplifierImpact sharedInstance] showImpact];

}
```

It works using it if I am viewing it on the ViewController, but the call using the

```
-(void)showVideos {

    [[ApplifierImpact sharedInstance] showImpact];    
}
```

Throws the error about window hierarchy when calling it from the SecondViewController.m file

Now, in the SecondViewController.h file, the only reference to ViewController, is a simple import of the .h file, should I be initialising it or giving it a property in there also?

Answer (score 0):

This: `ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];` creates a new `ViewController` object.  You then don't present it (i.e. don't give it access to the screen) but you ask it to `showVideos`.

I suspect what you really want is to get a reference to an **existing** `ViewController`.  When you create your `SecondViewController` give it a reference to the first one to act as a delegate.

Comment: Hi Phillip, that sounds exactly like what I need, how would I go about doing the 2nd method you mention?

Comment: That depends on how `SecondViewController` is created.  In the simple case where the first one creates and presents the second directly, create a delegate property in the second and, from the first, call something like `second.videoDelegate = self;`.  If you're putting up the second one using a segue, do the same thing but in the `prepareForSegue` method instead.

Comment: (When you want to call back to the first, you would use `[self.videoDelegate showVideos];` rather than creating anything new.)

Comment: Hmm, ok, the secondviewcontroller is presented in this method;

`SecondViewController *both = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    
    both.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    
    [self presentModalViewController:both animated:YES];`

I can use `[self.viewController showVideos];` without error in the SecondViewController, however it does not access it, I am guessing something is missing in the link?

Comment: What's the definition of `self.viewController` in the second controller?  (If it's what the name suggests, then you need to set it before doing the "present".  e.g. Something like `both.viewController = self;`.)

Comment: Still struggling here, if I use that final part, it shows code as I tested using an NSLOG, just not the video code, so it seems the way the video is being initialized is an issue, it is initialized in the AppDelegate.m file, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions part;

`[[ApplifierImpact sharedInstance] startWithGameId:@"1234567"andViewController:self.viewController];
    [[ApplifierImpact sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];`

I suspect the 'self.viewController' is an issue but I cannot use self on an AppDelegate as it gives an error :/

Comment: Afraid I've lost track of what the problem is at this point.  I thought it was about getting two controllers to talk to each other.  If there's a different issue now, you may need a new question with a new description.